# Getting value from dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, graph-theory, dynamic-allocation

I'm new to C programming so I am probably doing something really stupid here. I am trying to get the value from a 2D array that I read in from a text file ~70m lines.

When running the code, I get a seg fault and I have narrowed it down to line 10: if (i == graph[j][0])

```
void convertToCSR(int source, int maxNodes, int maxEdges, int* vertices, int* edges, int** graph) {
int i;
int j;
int edge = 0;

for (i = 0; i < maxNodes; i++) {
    vertices[i] = edge;

    for (j = 0; j < maxEdges; j++) {
        if (i == graph[j][0]) {
           //Sets edges[0] to the first position
            edges[edge] = graph[j][1];
            printf("new edge value: %d\n", edge);
           edge++;
         }
    }
}
vertices[maxNodes] = maxEdges;}
```

I have tried this with smaller datasets e.g 50 bytes and it works fine. With further testing, I print out the value of graph[0][0] and I get a seg fault.

The graph has loaded the data and was allocated like this:

```
int num_rows = 69000000;
graph = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * num_rows);
for(i=0; i < num_rows; i++){
    graph[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 );
}
```

I am also able to get the value of graph[0][0] outside of this method but not inside.What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help.

EDIT: In my main method, I am doing the following:

```
readInputFile(file);
int source = graph[0][0];
convertToCSR(source, maxNodes, maxEdges, nodes, edges, graph);
```

I have the correct value for the variable : source.
It seg faults in the convertToCSR method.

Comment: And your system have the at least 264 MiB (on a 32 bit system, double on a 64 bit) contiguous  free memory needed for the memory you want to allocate for `graph`? No `malloc` call returns a null pointer?

Comment: In my main method, I am able to get the value after I populate the graph. But when I call this method, it seg faults

Comment: why not check the `malloc()` return value. Run in `gdb` and do `bt` what it says ?

Comment: Just because it *seems* to work doesn't mean it *actually* works. That's one of the problems with [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which you probably have somewhere).

Comment: I get `1104000000` bytes required on x86_64 (69000000 * (8-bytes per pointer + 8-bytes for 2 int)). That's 1.1G just for the allocated storage - doable, but large. And that doesn't address any additional memory for the read. You need to **validate** each and every allocation to insure `malloc` does not fail.

Comment: If I used a system with more memory, would that potentially work?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `num_rows` to store a number bigger than int capacity.

So the actual value int num_rows is not 69000000, because of the Overflow.

Try to use `long unsigned int num_rows` instead.